# footnotes messed up

Tags: footnotes

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's Thesis and I've encountered a problem with the footnotes in my text. For some reason some footnotes are listed twice. But in the second appearance they don't contain any text (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCIXe.png)). Does anybody know how to get rid of those 'messed up' footnotes?

Info: Using `\footnotemark{}` and `\footnotetext{}` instead of `\tablefootnote{}` does not solve the Problem

If you need further information let me know

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
        \caption{Caption with Tablefootnote\tablefootnote{Tablefootnote in Caption of a Figure}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            Tablefootnote in a Table\tablefootnote{Tablefootnote in a Table}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is how my MWE compiles

[image: MWE]

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are perhaps some who will know what could cause this, but it would be much simpler to diagnose with a complete example that demonstrates the problem, a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1).

Comment: As far as I can see, the point of `tablefootnote` is that one doesn't need `\footnotetext`, so wouldn't the right thing be to use `\tablefootnote{Tablefootnote in Caption of a Figure}` and not have the `\footnotetext`? That doesn't solve the problem completely of course, as the footnote is still printed twice.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. yes you're right ... I updated the MWE

Comment: I might be wrong but from the documentation I do not see that it should work in a `figure` environment. It really seems to me that it works for tables (see also David Carlisle's answer).

Comment: @campa but using a `\footnotemark{}' and `\footnotetext{}` won't let me compile with following error:  **Argument of \@caption has an extra }**

Comment: @Jamie-505 they are fragile commands beinbg written to the list of tables, and you do not want footnotes when the caption is copied to the list of tables, that is why I used the optional argument to caption in my answer so te footnote is only in the body

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would it be enough to `\protect\footnotemark`, _as long as I don't use_ `\listoffigures`?

Comment: @campa yes but using the optional argument is safer, otherwise you will forget and will add \listoftables in a few months time:-)

Comment: Sorry... forget what? ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah ok good to know, but never the less I figured out a way solve my problem by using `\protect\footnotemark{}` and `\footnotetext{}` but this still leaves me with the problem for the list of figures

Comment: @Jamie-505 there isn't a problem for the list of figures, just use the optional argument provided for that purpose then you do not need \protect either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will, works like a charm, btw I edited your answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank entries are from your empty footnote in the caption, twice as a caption is set twice:

Using `\footnotemark{}` in Combination with the optional argument for `\caption[]{}` solves the Problem

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \caption[Caption with Footnote]
    {Caption with Footnote\footnotemark{}}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{Footnote in Caption of a Figure}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        Footnote in a Table\tablefootnote{Footnote in a Table}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pls have a look at my new mwe, I stripped out all unnecessary lines to make it more clear (for me and for others)

What do you mean by _caption is set twice_

Comment: @Jamie-505 internally a caption is set twice, once on a single line (in which case it is centred) but if that is too wide it is set as a paragraph, and the first setting discarded, but side effects like counter incrementing can show......